# Need to calculate Room allotment to the guest in a hotel according to the per room capacity in a hotel

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I looked out various articles but, couldn't find a way. So, posting here in hope of finding a logic for this particular python problem.

I am working on a hotel management system's book a room section. Here, the first system asks the user how many total guests then asks the total required rooms.
The hotel has the condition that one room allows up to 4 guests. And automatically auto-suggests a number of rooms should be taken to the guest if the guest entered the wrong count.

---

Sample output:

```
5
1

You cannot take 1 room. You shall take 2 rooms for 5 guests. Per room,  
only 4 guests are allowed.
```

Sample Output 2:

```
9
1
You cannot take 1 room. You shall take 3 rooms for 9 guests. Per room, 
only 4 guests are allowed.
```

---

```
room=[]
per_room = 4 # 4 guests in one room
guests = int(input("Guest(s) Count: ")) # takes total guests
total_rooms = int(input("Rooms Count: ")) # takes total room required by the guest

capacity = round(guests % per_room) # condition for according to one room occupancy 
if capacity != total_rooms:
    # you cannot take 1 room for 5 guests.
```

I am not able to figure out a way to show the room occupancy thing. I tried modulo but for the multiples of 4, it is giving the wrong rooms count suggestion.

I tried these,

total_guests%4
(total guests-per_room_capacity)% rooms required by the guest

Can anyone suggest a way to do this? I am stuck at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `math.ceil()` function for this.

```
import math

room = []
per_room = 4 # 4 guests in one room
guests = int(input("Guest(s) Count: ")) # takes total guests
total_rooms = int(input("Rooms Count: ")) # takes total room required by the guest

if total_rooms * per_room < guests: # Run if the guests can't fit in the rooms
    suggested_rooms = math.ceil(guests / per_room) # Find the amount of rooms needed to fit the guests
    print("You cannot take {} room(s). You shall take {} room(s) for {} guest(s). Per room, only {} guest(s) is/are allowed.".format(total_rooms, suggested_rooms, guests, per_room))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do what you are asking.

Essentially, you can perform integer division using the `//` operator. This will round down to one less room than is needed except for the case where `guests` is a multiple of 4, in which case it gives the desired result. So, if the number of `guests` is not a multiple of 4, we need to add 1. We can detect whether `guests` is a multiple of 4 using the modulo operator `%`, as shown below.

```
        per_room = 4 # 4 guests in one room
        test_cases = [(5, 1), (9, 1), (5, 2), (9, 2), (9, 3)]
        for guests, total_rooms in test_cases:
            #guests = int(input("Guest(s) Count: ")) # takes total guests
            #total_rooms = int(input("Rooms Count: ")) # takes total room required by the guest

            capacity = guests // per_room + (1 if guests % per_room else 0) # condition for according to one room occupancy 
            if capacity != total_rooms:
                print(f"You cannot take {total_rooms} room{'' if total_rooms == 1 else 's'}."
                      f" You shall take {capacity} room{'' if capacity == 1 else 's'} for "
                      f"{guests} guest{'' if guests == 1 else 's'}."
                      f" Per room, only {per_room} guest{' is' if per_room == 1 else 's are'} allowed.")
            else:
                print(f"Thank you for your reservation of "
                      f"{total_rooms} room{'' if total_rooms == 1 else 's'}"
                      f" for {guests} guest{'' if guests == 1 else 's'}.")
```

Here is the sample output:

```
You cannot take 1 room. You shall take 2 rooms for 5 guests. Per room, only 4 guests are allowed.`
You cannot take 1 room. You shall take 3 rooms for 9 guests. Per room, only 4 guests are allowed.`
Thank you for your reservation of 2 rooms for 5 guests.
You cannot take 2 rooms. You shall take 3 rooms for 9 guests. Per room, only 4 guests are allowed.`
Thank you for your reservation of 3 rooms for 9 guests.
```